# AngularJS $watch cookie expire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, watch

The backend returns this header:

`Set-Cookie: session_id=5734283c02b8755f85a5f622; Domain=topleveldomain.com; Expires=Thu, 12-May-2016 06:52:55 GMT; Max-Age=5; Secure; Path=/`

from `https://api.topleveldomain.com` and using `$cookies.get('session_id')` returns `5734283c02b8755f85a5f622`. However when I try to use `$watch` nothing seems to work:

```
$scope.$watch($cookies.get('session_id'), function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(oldValue);
    console.log(newValue);
});
```

nor

```
$scope.$watch(function() { return $cookies.get('session_id'); },
    function(newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
    }
);
```

nor either of the above with `true` as third parameter logs `undefined` after 5 seconds. It does not log `undefined` if I manually delete the cookie from the browser. The `$watch` are not triggered if i call `$cookies.remove('session_id`) either. I did try on both Firefox and Chrome without any success. How can I watch if a cookie is expired?

**EDIT: My current solution**

Since `$cookies.get()` seems to work, I made a quickfix:

```
$interval(function() {
    if($cookies.get('session_id') === undefined) {
        console.log('logged out');
    } else {
        console.log('still logged in');
    }
}, 2000);
```

However I find this "bad" style, since I am not really using proper AngularJS. However, until I find a proper solution, this is the code I am using